# Full list of currency / money formatting based on locale

Tags: localization, formatting, currency, money

I'm looking for a full list of currency / money formatting for each locale.
I know that for US for example 1500.00 USD would be formatted as

```
$ 1,500.00
```

Australian user would see `US$` instead of `$`. Some locales put the sign after the number i.e. `1,500.00 $`, other uses minus sign before the currency sign i.e. `-$ 1,500.00`. Some use space as grouping i.e: `$ 1 500.00` and etc and etc

The closest list I could find is
http://www.thefinancials.com/Default.aspx?SubSectionID=curformat

But it does not include the position of the minus sign and the currency symbol. Is there any standard that I can refer to in order to format money correctly for each locale?

Thank you!

Comment: I do not agree with duplication. I haven't found the answer with that link.

Comment: @GinoPane try this http://cldr.unicode.org/ This is the most complete data I was able to find. I'm pretty sure every programming language has an API to work with CLDR data

Comment: so I can rely on them? The problem is that I've checked internalization on Windows and it seems that they use different format for currencies.

Comment: As far as I understand CLDR data is published by the Unicode consortium an organization that responsible for the Unicode support. They should be very reliable.