# Valid currency formats by locale

Tags: localization, formatting, currency

Does anyone know where I can get a list of valid currency formats by locale code? I've extracted formats from Intl (js object) and compared to those, which we can see in Windows Regional Settings and saw that they are different. For example, for "be-BY" we have "$ 123,123.35" in Intl, but on Windows it is "123 123,35 $". It seems, that format from Intl is the same as provided by CLDR.

So what is correct? And is there a complete and correct list of this anywhere?

This: [Full list of currency / money formatting based on locale](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/71685/full-list-of-currency-money-formatting-based-on-locale) - does not help much.

Comment: You will find different parallel usage in many regions and probably some errors, but overall there is nothing better or more complete than the [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](http://cldr.unicode.org/), which is already mentioned in the question. Microsoft claims to rely on it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Crissov mentioned, CLDR is your best bet. There may be inconsistencies, but there are revisions regularly and it's open source.

In the case of `be-BY` itself, it's hard for someone without knowledge of slavic langauges like myself to do effective searches, but based on a couple of search results [including this supermarket](http://www.bel-market.by/), the x xxx $ format does seem to be preferred (I can't speak to decimals; Belarusian rubles no longer have decimal values, I believe). This doesn't seem to be universal though; this [Volkswagen site for Belarus](http://www.volkswagen.by/be.html#/teaser=9d81cac6a@3) gives values in US dollars with $ coming first).

If you know Belarus is a specific market you need to take into consideration, consider reaching out to a firm that can localize your content -- not just your prices but content more generally.